# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core web application in NET 6. When I run the `app.Run()` at program.cs, I got this error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists: Cookies'
```

I think this is the code that cause this issue. How should I reconfigure this?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);

    options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
})
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();


builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

and this is the code for logout:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    
Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, what you need do is to have two different authentication schemes like below:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyAzureAdScheme";
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
  
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);     
        options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    },null, "MyAzureAdScheme", null)   

    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Comment: When the program loads, it goes to `https://localhost:7293/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F` but it should go to `/signin-oidc`

Comment: Hi @Steve, your application contains two authentication scheme, by default it would use the cookie authentication, you need set the `options.DefaultChallengeScheme="MyAzureAdScheme"` to achieve your requirement. Check my updated answer.

Comment: It can login now. But when I logout , I got this error: 
`"No sign-out authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'OpenIdConnect'. The registered sign-out schemes are: Cookies, MyAzureAdScheme. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie(\"OpenIdConnect\",...)?"` I added the logout code in the original post

Comment: The error message is very clear, you define the authentication scheme with Cookies and `MyAzureAdScheme`. If you sign out with `OpenIdConnect`, the authentication scheme should be `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` instead of `MyAzureAdScheme` in your configuration of the Program.cs. Or you can sign out with scheme `MyAzureAdScheme`.  Besides, your original problem has been solved, if you have any other problem, pls post a new thread instead of asking in the original post.